# how to fit the best hybrid Gibbs model by spatstat?

Tags: r, hybrid, spatstat

I want fit a best hybrid model to a ppp with more than 100 points and a rectangle window, so do trial and error. it's natural to find the significant r for geyer model by looking into the centered L(r) plot where there are several peak and troughs on it. so i draw the centered L(r) function first:

```
L.inhom<-Linhom(my.X)
plot(L.inhom, iso-r~r,legend=FALSE)
```

then decide whether to include a hardcore (the first trough suggests a hardcore), and a geyer component(following peaks or troughs).
according to the spatstat book, one can alway use profilepl() to find the best (r,sat) for a Geyer saturation model

```
df<-expand.grid(r=seq(45,200, by=1),sat=c(1,2,3,4,5))    
p.Geyer<-profilepl(df,Geyer, my.X~1, correction="translate", aic=TRUE)
as.ppm(p.Geyer)   #(r=,sat=)
```

I feel that the  (r,sat) found by profilepl() is good enough for the global pattern of my ppp (is that right?). Indeed, a hybrid model include a hardcore and a geyer component with this (r,sat) parameters owns a much lower AIC than corresponding hardcore model and geyer saturation model.
after this, I fit the second hybrid model with hardcore and two geyer components, which is even better according to AICs. and I think the second hybrid model is also valid or good for my data, as the L(r) plot does present more than one peak and one trough.
I am thinking to use envelope of fitted model to judge its validity: if the fitted L(r) was bounded in the simulated envelope, then the model is good enough for the data.

```
env.hybrid.final<-envelope(hybrid.1, Linhom, 
                       simulate=expression(rpoispp(den.X)),
                       use.thoery=TRUE,nsim=19, global=TRUE)   
plot(env.hybrid.final,.-r~r, shade=NULL, legend=FALSE, 
     xlab="r",ylab="L(r)-r",  main = "")
```

here come the questions: 
q1: is it right using L(r) envelop plot to judge the validity of fitted model, as i did? if not, how to judge the best fitted model or even a "good" model?
q2: when you can fit several models to a dataset, how to decide when a model is good enough? especially when there no clear mechanism konwn. AIC?

Comment: Since this is about stats methods rather than code, it's more appropriate on [stats.se]; I've voted to have it moved over there. You might take a look there to find similar posts already up

Comment: thanks camile for the suggestion. in my experience, meothodology of spatial pattern anaylsis is quite different from most of the linear model-based statistics. therefore, it is better to let it be, which also may ease Mr. Badeley's reply.